# Initialize transient fields after object is created from database?

Tags: java, database, mongodb, serialization, morphia

I am using Morphia and MongoDB. When data is fetched the object is created using a default constructor without parameters and then the fields get initialized by using reflection (serializing libraries like Kryo and Jackson do this as well). This way it's not possible to add code depending on the values of the fields inside the constructor (Since they are not initialized with the data from the DB yet). I like to know if there is a way to run additional code after the object is fetched and created without actually calling a method manually after? The reason is I am storing partial data of an object and based upon it's own data and many references like to initialize additional transient fields. I can currently come up with 4 alternatives:

1. Run something like .initialize() when the object is
   fetched but whenever someone (including me) forgets to run that
   method problems start to happen.
2. Add those currently transient fields to the database but
   they change a lot during runtime and thus need to be updated
   frequently. Since there are a couple dozen per object I don't think
   this is a good method.
3. Remove the transient fields and add methods that
   return the values. This would add some extra work for my server but
   sounds like the best option at the moment.
4. Default all transient fields to null and whenever I need to get or set one of these I calculate and populate them whenever it is null.

I am currently using 1. but debating if I should either use 3 or 4. However if there is a better way to run some code after a object is created I would like to know.

Comment: Making the transient fields private and in the getter methods, check if the field has been initialized. If not initialized, then calculate the value and cache it. Could this be a combination of 3 and 4?

Comment: @WangSheng it actually is 4. Does mean I have to use an Object instead of primmitives but that should not be an issue.

Comment: sorry, I thought "add methods" meant adding getters and setters. then it is the 4th option. I think using a wrapper rather than a primitive is totally fine. The other alternative I can think of is have a single field called `initialized = false`, and an `init` method. In each of the getters, check `initialized` and if `false` call `init` method.

Comment: @WangSheng I now have a single `initialize` method that initializes all the fields and call it from each `get` method when it's null. However this still feels weirs since now I am adding additional methods like `changeFieldBy(int amount)` and now I feel like I have to check for null again or catch a `npe` even though it's unlikely to be null how I use the code. I guess I have to do the same for a `initialized` boolean. All options feel either hacky or unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `@PostLoad` to run your `initialize()` and Morphia automatically call that method for you when it's done loading data in to the new instance f

Comment: exactly what I was looking for I must have read over it at the [Annotation section](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/guides/lifeCycleMethods/).

Comment: could you accept the answer so others can find it more easily then?  Thanks.